# How to deserialize xml to object in C#, If some xml missing in the xml

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I had one xml payload, there are lot of xml elements available, I have declared all the elements in the class properties, when I tried to serialize it came with all nodes, Here I have removed some xml elements before deserialize, then am trying to deserialize the xml, here am getting error.

Is that possible to deserialize without declared elements? I need to deserialize without some elements. Because deserialize xml payload is dynamic, it is coming from another vendor. Please help me.

Code Block:

Class:

```
[Serializable]
public class CSSngSectorCable
{
    [XmlElement("cableID")]
    public Int32 CSSngCableId { get; set; }
    public string RFDSSection { get; set; }
    public string RFDSSector { get; set; }
    public Int32 RFDSCableNumber { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("cableNumber")]
    public string CSSngCableNumber { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("feederType")]
    public string CSSngFeederType { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("feederLength")]
    public string CSSngFeederLength { get; set; }
    public int CableRowNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Code to serialize:

```
var cables= new SectorCable();
///added some code
string serializevalue = SerializationHelper.SerializeToXml(cables, true);
```

Serialize Output:

```
<cable>
      <cableID>1</cableID>
      <cableNumber>2</cableNumber>
      <feederType>15.24</feederType>
      <feederLength></feederLength>
</cable>
```

Data to deserialize:

```
<cable>
<cableID>1</cableID>
<cableNumber>2</cableNumber>
</cable>
```

Code for deserialize:

```
public CSSngSectorCable GetCableFromDynamicXML(StreamReader reader)
    {
        try
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CSSngSectorCable));
            var cables = (CSSngSectorCable)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            return cables;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
```

Here it's not working fine it's throw exception. How to resolve the issue.

Comment: What exception is it throwing? What's the XML that's throwing the exception? You likely need to share more information before you'll get a useful answer.

Comment: `XmlSerializer` will and should properly deserialize missing values. Deserialization works as following: instance of the object is created first (so **all** its properties have default values), if values are present in the xml then they are set (overwriting default). Any missing in the xml property will have default value, which totally ok. So, what exception you get and what is the issue?

Answer (score 6):

```
 public class MyClass
 {
   [XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]
   public string Group;
   }
```